# Rails `form_with` when having a `has_one` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

Rails assumes that my `has_one` association is plural. Please take a look at my cide snippet:

My model:

```
class Order  < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order_detail
end
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
resources :orders do
  resource :order_detail
end
```

My `views/order_details/new.rb`:

```
...
<%= form_with(model: [@order, @order_detail]) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Navigating to `localhost:3000/orders/1/order_detail/new`. The error I get is this:

```
undefined method `order_order_details_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff9be1b66a0>:0x00007ff9be1b4cd8>
Did you mean?  order_order_detail_path
               order_order_detail_url
```

I know that the route should evaluate to `order_order_detail_path`, but the array apparently doesn't do this.

How to fix this?

Comment: You can just override the `url` if you want `form_with(model: [@order, @order_detail], url: order_order_detail_path(@order) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up and solved it by making the `:order_details` plural.

```
resources :orders do
  resource :order_details
end
```

The `has_one` association will still work in the controller and params.